# book style using \fancyheader with \frontmatter but "Preface" shows up in header as CHAPTER 0. PREFACE only on odd pages?

Tags: fancyhdr

```
\fancypagestyle{fancybook}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    
\renewcommand*{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright{\thesection\ ##1} }%
    \renewcommand*{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter: ##1}{} }%
    
    \fancyhfoffset[LE]{6mm}% slightly less than 0.25in
    \fancyhfoffset[RO]{6mm}%
    %
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage\hskip3mm\vrule\hskip3mm\leftmark}%
    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark\hskip3mm\vrule\hskip3mm\thepage}%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frontmatter

\pagenumbering{roman}

\title {book title here}
\author{name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents      
\cleardoublepage

%\thispagestyle{plain} 

\renewcommand\bibname{References}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\normalsize
\begin{singlespace}
\chapter{Preface}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
\input{content/0_preface}

\chapter{Acknowledgments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgments}
\input{content/0_acknow}
\end{singlespace}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}% no header on otherwise empty pages

\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{fancybook}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhfoffset[LE]{6mm}% slightly less than 0.25in
  \fancyhfoffset[RO]{6mm}%
  \fancyhead[LE]{%
    \thepage\hspace{3mm}\vrule\hspace{3mm}%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
      \MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ }%
    \fi
    \leftmark
  }%
  \fancyhead[RO]{%
    \rightmark
    \hspace{3mm}\vrule\hspace{3mm}\thepage
  }%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\pagestyle{fancybook}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\title{book title here}
\author{name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents      

\chapter{Preface}

This is the text of the preface

\lipsum[1-10]

\chapter{Acknowledgments}

This is the text of the acknowledgments

\lipsum[1-10]

\mainmatter

\chapter{The first chapter}

\section{A section}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Note that `\frontmatter` issues `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\mainmatter` issues `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, so there's no need to have again those declarations.

Chapters in the front matter are automatically added to the table of contents.

I'm not sure I'd like to have the small vertical rule moving depending on the length of the page number.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That works GREAT and thank you so much. I will incorporate to see if it works with my code. VERY much appreciated!! More later!

Comment: ...and thank you for the education on this!

Comment: ONE QUESTION i did have -- i have a PART I and a PART II dividing up the book (1012 pgs), How can i remove the header (e.g. Acknowledgements) from "only one" page?

Comment: @maxshredder I'm not sure what having two parts has to do with the header of the acknowledgment chapter.